# Get current user access level in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

In Joomla 2.5.14, I have a script that gets the current user group id, like:

```
$groups = $user->get('groups');
foreach($groups as $group) {
    echo "<p>Your group ID is:" . $group . "</p>";
};
```

Now, I need to count the number of articles this user is able to read, given his access level.

For that, I need to select the access level from the viewlevels table, that looks like this:

```
id     title            rules JSON encoded access control.
1   Public      [1]
2   AccessA     [13,8,16,17]
3   AccesssF    [8]
4   AccessD     [14,8]
6   AccessB     [8,16,17]
7       AccessC     [8,17]
```

So, for example, Group 17 may read the articles in AccessA, AccessB and Access C.

I tried the following query, but it isn't selecting any rows:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM xmb9d_viewlevels WHERE rules LIKE '%.$group.%'";
```

How can I select all the acess levels for the current user group and then count the number of articles he's able to read?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the periods from within the LIKE clause.  Such as:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM xmb9d_viewlevels WHERE rules LIKE '%$group%'";
```

Also, to make it not specific to the database you should substitute #__ (Note: it's two underscores) for the table prefix:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM #__viewlevels WHERE rules LIKE '%$group%'";
```

Comment: It worked fine, thanks! Now, how do I count the number of articles from table __content, using the result of this selection? Should I pass the result of the selection to a variable and then use it in another query or is it possible to write a single query?

Comment: How about this,   $query="SELECT count(*) FROM #__content WHERE access in (select id from #__viewlevels where rules LIKE '%$group%'";

Comment: Actually, count(*) is bad to use.  I would suggest:  $query="SELECT count(id) FROM #__content WHERE access in (select id from #__viewlevels where rules LIKE '%$group%'";

Comment: Hi, I tried:

$query="SELECT count(id) FROM #__content WHERE access in (SELECT id FROM #__viewlevels WHERE rules LIKE '%$group%')";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {
 
    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* store result */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
 
    /* Conta o número de artigos por nível de acesso!" ; */
 
    $nartigos=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
 
    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
};

echo "Nº de artigos " .$nartigos;

I get the error: Notice: Undefined variable: nartigos

Comment: You're much better off using the api than trying to do it with a query.

Comment: beware if you remove the dots from %$group%, then group id 1 will match groups id 11, 21, 31 etc.

Answer (score 4):

First
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/access/access.php#L285

```
JAccess::getGroupsByUser($userId, $recursive = true)
```

Will get you the groups a user is matched to including via inheritance (unless you make $recursive false)

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/access/access.php#L402

`JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($userId)` will give you all the view levels a user is allowed to see as an array.

If you do

```
$allowedViewLevels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($userId);
```

if nothing else you could do

```
$implodedViewLevels = implode(',', $allowedViewLevels);

....

$query->select($db->quoteName('id'))
->from('#__content')
->where($db->quoteName('access') . 'IN (' . $implodedViewLevels . ')';
 ....
```

(not tested but you get the general idea).
In joomla always try to let the api do the work for you rather than fight with it.

Comment: Hi,explode won't work on an array. But I get the idea. Perhaps I can loop through the array and build a string of access levels, separated by a comma that I can use in the query.